# Uso del Int 21 42h para la lectura de un fichero

Tags: ensamblador

Al tratar de usar el `int 21` `42H` para moverme mi a mi siguiente linea, este imprime vació. Ya he intentado desplazarme con `AL 00` y `AL 01`. Solo parece funcionar con `AL 02`. Como se podría desplazar a la siguiente linea una de vez de hacer el primer read? Por el momento estoy tratando de desplazarme a la segunda linea e imprimir la R. La confusión nace cuando tengo que manipular `CX:DX`. Nunca se mueve para adelante, mucho menos para abajo.

Codigo:

```
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.model tiny
.data   
  filename db "boolean.txt", 0 
  bufferSize = 512 
  filehandle dw ?
  buffer  db  200 dup (?) 
   .code  
        Org 0100H     
start:                                     ;Comienzo de Programa
  CALL init
  CALL open
  CALL cursor
  CALL read
  CALL show
  CALL close
  CALL waiting
  CALL ending
  INT 20H

; Inicializamos la pantalla 
init: MOV AH,00H
       MOV AL,03H
       INT 10H
       RET

;Esperamos una tecla
waiting: MOV  AH, 07H
                INT 21H
                RET           

;Terminamos el programa
ending: MOV AX, 4C00H  
                INT 21H 
                RET

;Abrimos del programa
open: MOV AH,3DH   
            MOV AL,0H   
            MOV DX, offset filename  
            INT 21H                 
            MOV filehandle, AX   
            RET   

;Movemos el cursor dentro del archivo.
  cursor: MOV  AH, 42H          
                MOV  AL, 00H      
                MOV  BX, filehandle    
                MOV CX,1
                MOV DX,1
                INT  21H  
                RET        

;Lectura del archivo
read: MOV AH, 3FH     
           MOV BX, filehandle    
           MOV DX, offset buffer   
           INT 21H   ; AX tendra los bytes transferidos
           RET

;Cerramos del archivo
close: MOV AH, 3EH  
             MOV BX, filehandle  
             INT 21H 
             RET 

; Mostramos
show: MOV AH,09H 
             MOV AL,DS:[buffer]
             MOV BL,2EH
             MOV DX,0000H
             MOV CX,0001H
             INT 10H
             RET

; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
End Start        ;Fin de Programa
```

Fichero en cuestion:

> 1.Pregunta?$
>   Respuesta 1$
>   Respuesta 2$
>   Respuesta 3$
>   Respuesta 4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te comparto un código en MASM que yo hice, el archivo al que queras tener acceso tiene que estar en la carpeta que montes como disco duro en caso de usar un emulador como DOSBOX. Saludos.

```
    ;===============SECCION DE MACROS ===========================
    print macro cadena 
    LOCAL ETIQUETA 
    ETIQUETA: 
        MOV ah,09h 
        MOV dx,@data 
        MOV ds,dx 
        MOV dx, offset cadena 
        int 21h
    endm

    getRuta macro buffer
    LOCAL INICIO,FIN
        xor si,si
    INICIO:
        getChar
        cmp al,0dh
        je FIN
        mov buffer[si],al
        inc si
        jmp INICIO
    FIN:
        mov buffer[si],00h
    endm

    getChar macro
    mov ah,01h
    int 21h
    endm

    abrirF macro ruta,handle
    mov ah,3dh
    mov al,00h
    lea dx,ruta
    int 21h
    mov handle,ax
    jc ErrorAbrir
    endm

    leerF macro numbytes,buffer,handle
    mov ah,3fh
    mov bx,handle
    mov cx,numbytes
    lea dx,buffer
    int 21h
    jc ErrorLeer
    endm

    crearF macro buffer,handle
    mov ah,3ch
    mov cx,00h
    lea dx,buffer
    int 21h
    mov handle,ax
    jc ErrorCrear
    endm

    ;================= DECLARACION TIPO DE EJECUTABLE ============
    .model small 
    .stack 100h 
    .data 
    ;================ SECCION DE DATOS ========================
    encab db 0ah,0dh, '1) Abrir archivo', 0ah,0dh,'2) Crear Archivo',0ah,0dh,'3) Salir',0ah,0dh,'$'
    msm1 db 0ah,0dh,'FUNCION ABRIR','$'
    msm2 db 0ah,0dh,'FUNCION CREAR','$'
    msmError1 db 0ah,0dh,'Error al abrir archivo','$'
    msmError2 db 0ah,0dh,'Error al leer archivo','$'
    msmError3 db 0ah,0dh,'Error al crear archivo','$'
    rutaArchivo db 100 dup('$')
    bufferLectura db 100 dup('$')
    handleFichero dw ?
    .code ;segmento de código
    ;================== SECCION DE CODIGO ===========================
        main proc 
            Menu:
                print encab
                getChar
                cmp al,49
                je ABRIR
                cmp al,50
                je CREAR
                cmp al,51
                je SALIR
                jmp Menu
            ABRIR:
                print msm1
                getRuta rutaArchivo
                abrirF rutaArchivo,handleFichero
                leerF SIZEOF bufferLectura,bufferLectura,handleFichero
                print bufferLectura
                getChar
                jmp Menu
            CREAR:
                print msm2
                getRuta rutaArchivo
                crearF rutaArchivo,handleFichero
                getChar
                jmp Menu
            ErrorAbrir:
                print msmError1
                getChar
                jmp Menu
            ErrorLeer:
                print msmError2
                getChar
                jmp Menu
            ErrorCrear:
                print msmError3
                getChar
                jmp Menu
            SALIR: 
                MOV ah,4ch 
                int 21h
        main endp
    ;================ FIN DE SECCION DE CODIGO ========================
    end
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!